# Axios Error Response: How to read Request Method when handling error in catch clause

Tags: javascript, axios

I'd like to be able to read what the request method of my axios API call is when I am catching an error due to a bad request. Basically, I need to be able to handle errors differently depending on if the request method is of type GET vs type POST/PUT.

I see that the Fetch API has a method that would give the behaviour that's similar to what I'm looking for, [like this here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request/method)

Thanks for all help.

Comment: I don't think the error itself contains the request method. If you are using internal APIs then you could potentially return the request method in the error response.

Comment: @UsmanJ Hey, thanks for your reply. Okay, that sounds like a good solution. Do you know of the best way I can send the request method type as a string/etc in a persistent way, which would then be accessible through a (error) response object?

Comment: Can't you just extract the request method from the request itself rather than sending the method as part of the request? What framework are you using for your APIs?

Comment: Well, I figured this out on my own. Overcomplicating things as always! #JuniorLife 

Thanks anyways, bud :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question. Pass your callback in the catch clause as you normally would, and define `error` as the first parameter.

The request method type is accessible in the axios catch block via: `error.response.config.method`